# Users able to install applications

Tags: windows-7, security

We have win7. Network users are able to download applications like Mozilla Firefox, and install it. The install folder they are able to install to is c:\users%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Mozilla. If they are able to install to this folder, they can install malware. Any ideas to prevent them from installing programs to this folder?

Comment: It is unnecessary to refer to Chrome as malware. Do you want to start a flame war?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [AppLocker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd548340%28WS.10%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, AppLocker can be used to prevent applications/programs that we are aware of, can AppLocker be used to prevent users from running .vbs or any other scripts. Sorry didn't mean to refer chrome as a malware

Comment: Yes. AppLocker has two different modes, block all except whitelist OR allow all except blacklist. It can identify programs by name/extension, signature, path, or hash. Different policies can be implemented by user, group, computer, site, domain, and organizational unit. It's a very extensive and complete application policy utility.